# libGLESv2 PowerVR SGX symbols

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, crash-dumps

I have got a segmentation fault and looking at the crash dump it seems to have something to do with

/system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so

While I know it is probably something in my code that is causing the problem, I don't even know where to begin to look. Plus I cannot find symbols for that lib, so I don't know what function it is dying in.

Anyone know where I can get the symbols for this lib?

Comment: An API trace will usually help in these sorts of situations. Most platforms provide a mechanism to log all of the GL API calls complete with passed parameters. Often crashes will occur when you try to dereference a NULL pointer in a call to `glBufferData (...)`, these calls will be the last call you see in a trace prior to a crash. Other times you may have supplied an invalid enumerant to an API call 20-30 calls earlier, these are harder to diagnose but combined with `glGetError (...)` status you will not have to stumble around in the dark at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the OpenGL ES 2.x driver implementation for a device with an IMG PowerVR GPU.

It's distributed as a "binary blob".  Symbols are not available.

Usually when you crash in a GL driver it's because either (a) you're passing bad inputs to GL, or (b) you're trashing the heap at an earlier point, and crashing when GL stumbles over the corruption.  It could also be a bug in the driver itself, but that's relatively unlikely.